# Which subcontractor installs 2" foam board at footings and on poured walls?

Tags: insulation, basement, waterproofing, cement, footings

Please, which sub installs the 2" foam board (northern climate) on footings and the poured concrete basement walls?  excavator, or cement contractor, insulation contractor or ?

Hubby and I are going to build a new house and want to know who to ask to do that part.

Answer (score 1):

The concrete contractor does, it goes in over the gravel bed and under the poly moisture barrier and reinforcing wire or rebar. There also needs to be foam at the edge of the floor slab to create a thermal break between the foundation wall and floor slab.

Depending on your conditions, you may need drain tile under the slab too.